# Removing key-mon

Tags: python, uninstall, pip

I wanted to try key-mon program on Ubuntu 20.04. I wasn't quite sure this is a safe program, so I tried installing it on my test bed on Ubuntu 18.04.

I might have installed it using `sudo apt-get install keymon`, but I followed the instruction in their homepage. I downloaded the file, https://code.google.com/archive/p/key-mon/downloads, unzipped it, and `sudo python setup.py install`. It seems to be working fine after solving the error message, `no module named pygtk`, using `sudo apt-get install python-gtk2 libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module`.

I thought key-mon is a safe program since it worked out in Ubuntu 18.04. So I got bold, and I installed it on my machine with Ubuntu 20.04. Unfortunately, it didn't work. What they say is Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't support the python-gtk2. I couldn't solve the error.

I've decided not to use key-mon. Now all the trouble is coming. Since I've installed it using `sudo python setup.py install` not sudo apt-get install keymon". I can't figure out how to remove it on Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Of course, `sudo apt-get remove key-mon` doesn't work. Some people say I should use pip. I'm not familiar with pip, but I tried.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip uninstall key-mon
```

It didn't work out.

Anyone knows how to remove key-mon completely in Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04. When I do `which key-mon` on the terminal. I get `/usr/local/bin/key-mon`. I don't want to see it anymore since it is deprecated on Ubuntu 20.04. I want to uninstall python, pip, key-mon, keymon, whatever it is connected to key-mon all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the file installed by rerunning the program, with extra parameter.

```
sudo python setup.py install --record install.txt
```

Here python will output list of installed files to file named exactly `install.txt`, you can view/inspect this file later on to make sure everything is correct.

Now what you want to do is remove the file listed on `install.txt`.

```
xargs sudo rm -rf < install.txt
```

If there are no errors, good then— everything seems to work as expected, try locate `key-mon` to see if it is still there.

#### Before

```
/tmp/key-mon-1.17$ command -v key-mon
/usr/local/bin/key-mon
/tmp/key-mon-1.17$ which key-mon
/usr/local/bin/key-mon
/tmp/key-mon-1.17$
```

#### After

```
/tmp/key-mon-1.17$ command -v key-mon
/tmp/key-mon-1.17$ which key-mon
/tmp/key-mon-1.17$
```

Comment: Thanks man. I'm quite satisfied with your solution. I also manually removed the folder itself, /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keymon. It was horrible experience with key-mon or keymon. Thanks.

Comment: I also did "sudo apt-get remove python2". Then, I confirmed the folder, /usr/local/lib/python2.7/ is gone. I tried removing python3 in Ubuntu 18.04. I shouldn't have done it. I reinstalled it.

Comment: @Smile Yeah, removing python related was never a good idea, as some of Ubuntu apps heavily relies on Python.

Answer (score 0):

try this ! It works fine with me on Ubuntu 20.04.

(1) http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

(2) http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/key-mon/key-mon_1.17-1ubuntu1_all.deb

I had very weird issue with Key-mon at first place as it won't allow me to run at any cost after it is installed successfully.

Then I changed the location from Asia (INDIA) [in my case] to (New York) during installation (re-install) of Ubuntu itself and followed the steps (1) & (2) as mentioned above. After that it works like a charm.

So try to re-install Ubuntu and follow the same, if you really need it.

Hope it works for you as well !!

Comment: The question was about removing key-mon - I don't really see you address that.